# Shape Keys from hooks

Tags: bezier-curves, shape-keys

I have animation that contains curves that are acting like cable. The curves vertices are attached (hook) to empty so it will work right way. Everything works fine, but I need to import this animation to unreal engine 4 and you can't import curve or hooks. The hook modifier has button "apply as shape key" but I can't make it work. Is there any tutorials or can someone explain to me how can I convert hooks to shape keys.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be using a rig with according weight painting. Unreal should be able to import that. Also posting an image might help finding the right answer!

Comment: I can't post image because of the model has NDA.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to make the curves as mesh and let the hooks be where they are. Then I creat new bones, that are attached to the hook. Now I can attache vertex groub to bone and then I can imoport the whole think.